# Hibernation problems on multi-headed desktops

Tags: multiple-monitors, hibernate

I have a laptop running 22.04 (Wayland) with two external displays. I have hibernation working on my system now by typing:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

However it intermittently fails. The failure appears to happen when my monitors lose input during the hibernation process and start auto-detection of inputs. My suspicion is that when it reselects the proper input the hibernation process is interrupted.

It is not possible to configure my monitors to disable input auto-selection.

My only workaround at the moment is to switch to a virtual console first before issuing the hibernate command. But that's really cumbersome, requiring multiple logins and console switching both before and after hibernation. If I try turning off the monitors before issuing the hibernate command, the hibernate never completes properly.

Does anyone have suggestions for a more convenient workaround or fix for this issue?